# How to set for fake value into input type file using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to set for fake value into input type file using javascript ?

i use this javascript code

```
document.getElementById("test").value = "C:\fakepath\test.jpg";
```

for set fake value into input type file id `test`
.

```
<input name="test" id="test" type="file">
```

but show error text like this

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
```

I want to know, how can i set fake value into input type file ?

Comment: You can't - as per the error message.  [What are you _trying_ to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Why do you want to set a fake value for the file input?

Comment: You won't be able to get a file from the user disk unless they select it. The error is saying you can only *clear* the input (by setting it to an empty string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the value due to security reasons, but you can make it appear so.

```css
.fakefile{font-family:arial;font-size:13px}
.fakefile INPUT{width:100px;}
.fakefile SPAN{display:inline-block;background:#fff;padding-left:4px;}
```

```html
<!-- Original -->
<input name="test" id="test" type="file">

<hr>
<!-- Fake -->
<div class="fakefile"><input name="test" id="test" type="file"><span>fakefilename.pdf</span></div>
```

Comment: There's an N that still shows, though. Good idea, anyways.

Comment: @Juan Ferrer I see, the button length is dependent on the browser and system language. You can also fake the whole thing by making your own button to trigger the upload.